# TLS1.2 DHE-RSA server key exchange signature generation

Tags: https, tls1.2

[this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/99877/rsa-signature-on-tls)
is very close to what I am looking for. It says

```
Some bytes are added before the concatenation of t and x, so as to obtain the following structure:
00 01 FF FF ... FF 00 t x
```

I want to know the way how to generate t exactly.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be you should just capture an TLS1.2 DHE-RSA handshake, then extract "t" and paste it into an ASN.1 decoder to see what is around the OID of the hash function (which should be the main part of "t" according to the post you linked).

Comment: It was Sequence, object identifier, object, and length and some more. But I could not guess what the object hex means.

Comment: And I also want to know general rule to make t.

Comment: I don't know why rfc5246 does not say anything about this.